# Store/retrieve data doesn't work using node

Tags: web3js, solc, ganache-cli

i trying something simple, store and retrieve a data in a smart contract, but when i want to retrieve the data, nothing is returned.

solc version is 0.4.24
web3 version is 1.2

Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract tbdocs {

    address owner;

    string testData;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function setTestData(string data) public returns (string) {
        testData = data;
        return testData;
    }

    function getTestData() public view returns (string) {
        return testData;
    }

}
```

Node Js code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const Web3 = require('web3');     // Version 1.2
const solc = require('solc');     // Version 0.4.24


async function compileAndDeplot() {

    const simplePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'simpleStore.sol');
    const sourceSolidity = fs.readFileSync(simplePath, 'utf8');

    const contract = solc.compile(sourceSolidity, 1).contracts[':tbdocs']

    const byteCode = contract.bytecode;
    const abi = JSON.parse(contract.interface);

    console.log('Compiled.');


    const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const address = accounts[0];
    console.log('Using account: ' + address);

    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)

    var contractDeployed = await myContract.deploy({
        data: byteCode
    }).send({
        from: address,
        gas: '2900000'
    }, function (error, transactionHash) {
        console.log('Transaction hash: ' + transactionHash);
    });

    const contractAddress = contractDeployed.options.address;

    console.log('Contract deployed at: ' + contractAddress);

    console.log('\nCalling methods: ')

    var result = await contractDeployed.methods.getOwner().call();
    console.log('\tgetOwner: ' + result);       // Works


    contractDeployed.methods.setTestData('testing store data').call()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('\tSet: ' + result);

            contractDeployed.methods.getTestData().call()
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('\tGet: ' + data);
                });
        })
}

compileAndDeplot();
```

Right now and testing with ganache-cli, but the same result with geth.

```
ganache-cli -u 0 -l 1000000000
```

Example output:

```
Compiled.
Using account: 0xdf6c7a3c1d19DfEF9bae7fC1328f182D781f6631
Transaction hash: 0xad8d9f164d7ec16522eab2a17c8d2c4253f52d0b648a7921b63c6b8bb863f9de
Contract deployed at: 0x0Aa3916BD95B5C02E8ee44c4E9ccf5FAaa328a0a

Calling methods:
    getOwner: 0xdf6c7a3c1d19DfEF9bae7fC1328f182D781f6631
    Set: testing store data
    Get:
```

As can be seen, the get is empty.

The contract works fine, can be tested here:

[Ethfiddle](https://ethfiddle.com/QDvuLO67St)

Thank for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all wrong:

```
    var result = await contractDeployed.methods.getOwner().call();
    console.log('\tgetOwner: ' + result);       // Works

    contractDeployed.methods.setTestData('testing store data').call()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('\tSet: ' + result);
            contractDeployed.methods.getTestData().call()
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('\tGet: ' + data);
                });
        });
```

The first `var result` that you have declared is not being used further down your code.

This is because the callback of function `setTestData` uses a variable of the exact same name (in the line `.then(result => {`).

Also note that function `setTestData` is not constant (neither `pure` nor `view`).

So while you can rely on its return-value when you call it on-chain (i.e., from this contract or from another contract), you cannot rely on its return-value when you call it off-chain (i.e., from a web3 script), where it will return the transaction hash instead.

Finally (and as also noted in the other answer), because this function is not constant, you should be using `send` instead of `call`.

Since you're using the `async`/`await` scheme anyway, you may as well do this:

```
    var result = await contractDeployed.methods.getOwner().call();
    console.log('\tgetOwner: ' + result);

    var options = {from: address, gas: ...};
    await contractDeployed.methods.setTestData('testing store data').send(options);

    var data = await contractDeployed.methods.getTestData().call();
    console.log('\tGet: ' + data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a call, which will treat the function as view and it will not generate a transaction.

```
contractDeployed.methods.setTestData('testing store data').call()
```

You have to use send (like in deploy)

```
contractDeployed.methods.setTestData('testing store data').send({
    from: address
})
```